# jQuery - Find element with custom attribute inside a table row

Tags: jquery

I have a table that looks like something below (just some pseudo code)

```
<table>
<tr><td>text11</td><td>text12</td><td><div customerid='1'>Customer 1</div></td></tr>
<tr><td>text21</td><td>text22</td><td><div>Customer 2</td></tr>
<tr><td><div customerid='2'>xxxx-yyyyy</div><td>text23</td><td>text33</td></tr>
</table>
```

I am iterating over each row of the table. I need to find out element in a row that has a custom attribute for example "customerid" as shown in above example. Few requirements of this search.

- The cell is not fixed where this custom attribute will appear
- HTML element type is not fixed on which this custom attribute will appear. That means any selector like $('div') etc. is out of question.
- Search will be performed at individual row level and not at table level

Here is what i was trying that seems to return "undefined" all the time.

```
rows = $(self.find('tbody tr').each(function (rowIndex, element) {
  var keyValue = getKeyValue($(element));                  
}));

function getKeyValue(row){
  return row.attr('customerid');
}
```

.attr method does not seem to work. I have debugged to verify that 'row' is actually correct table row and HTML is correct as well and contains a cell with a div that has my custom attribute on it.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: On top of the answers provided, you should have a think about using the `data-` attributes instead of making up your own.

Comment: This is a custom attribute and configurable. The user can decide to use any attribute name. This name comes in one of the options of the plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the attribute selector `[customerid]` to find the element that has this attribute, whatever that might be.

For example, when iterating over each row you can do:

```
rows = $(self.find('tbody tr').each(function (rowIndex, element) {
    var keyValue = $(this).find("[customerid]").eq(0).attr("customerid");
}));
```

Or, you could start by finding all elements with a customer id and work backwards to find the rows in which they appear:

```
self.find('tbody tr [customerid]').each(function() {
    var keyValue = this.getAttribute("customerid");
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
});
```

Comment: I kept missing square bracket in selector in my previous alternate attempts. All set now!